# Unable to Install .net framework in Windows 2012 server

Tags: windows-8, windows-server-2012, .net-3.5

I was trying to add .net 3.5 features in a (Remote) Windows 2012 server. But I am getting the following exception.

> Do you need to specify an alternate source path? One or more
>   installation selections are missing source files on the destination
>   server. The server will try to get missing source files from Windows
>   Update, or from a location that is specified by Group Policy. You can
>   also click the “Specify an alternate source path” link on this page to
>   provide a valid location for the source files.

I have tried to download and install using setup of framework 3.5 and that also failed.

I have seen several workarounds for this from the below URL

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734782

Is it possible to add .net 3.5 without using Installation media(of OS)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, it is not. Win 8 has the same 'issue'.

Comment: I am working on my client's PC as a Remote Machine. What is the best possible method to add .net framework 3.5

Comment: Ask them to put the media in the drive?

Comment: I have solved this by Selecting "Contact Windows Update directly to download repair content instead of Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) " Checkbox in Edit Group policy screen, as suggested in method 2 of the above URL

Comment: You should post this as the answer :) This question should be on superuser though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved this by Selecting "**Contact Windows Update directly to download repair content instead of Windows Server Update Services (WSUS)**" Checkbox in Edit Group policy screen, as suggested in method 2 of the above URL

Comment: The URL from the question (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734782) seems to concern itself mostly with network issues. Can you add all the steps you took to solve this problem in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your installation media path, after installing Windows server, follow the following step:

> If you want to specify an alternative source file, in the Alternate
>   source file path box, specify a fully qualified path of a shared
>   folder that contains the contents of the dvd:\sources\sxs folder from
>   the installation media.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for everyone, but worked in my scenario.

I had a server which allowed me to install .NET and another that didn't.
I copied the C:\windows\WinSxS\ directory from the working server to C:\WinSxS\ on the non-working server then pointed to this copied directory when it asked for a new source location. It even remembered the location when I went back to install other features.